# EventCallback of Childcomponent to an other ChildComponent, : Blazor

Tags: blazor, webassembly

EDIT::WORKING SOLUTION

I am trying to solve the problem when uploading a file ((in the)/through) FileUpload component,
that the FileDownload component which got a child DownloadTable component doesn't update, it only works when I force a refresh, because it reloads the webapplication which I want to avoid.

[image]

**Index.razor**

```
    @page "/"


    <h1>Drag/drop file viewer</h1>

    <p>Shows how you can present a custom UI instead of the native file input.</p>

    <FileUpload RefreshPageDownload="RefreshPageDownload"/>

    <FileDownload State="State" />

    @code {
        [Inject]
         public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

        public bool State { get; set; }
        public async Task RefreshPageDownload(int input)
        {
            await Task.CompletedTask;
            State = !State;
        }
    }
```

**FileUpload.razor**

```
<div id="drag-drop-zone">
    <InputFile OnChange="UploadFile" multiple />
    @status
</div>

@code {
    const string DefaultStatus = "Drop a text file here to view it, or click to choose a file";
    const int MaxAllowedFiles = 5;
    string status = DefaultStatus;

    List<Upload> uploadList = new();

    [Inject]
    IUploadService _uploadService { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> RefreshPageDownload { get; set; }


    async Task UploadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        uploadList.Clear();
        foreach (var input in e.GetMultipleFiles(MaxAllowedFiles))
        {

            var buffers = new byte[input.Size];
            await input.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffers);
        
            var u = new Upload {
                Content =  buffers,
                MimeType = input.ContentType,
                Name = input.Name,
                Date = input.LastModified.DateTime,
                Size = input.Size
            };

            uploadList.Add(u);
        }

        await _uploadService.UploadFile(uploadList);

        await RefreshParent();
    }

    public async Task RefreshParent()
    {
        await RefreshPageDownload.InvokeAsync(1);
    }
}
```

**FileDownload**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <!-- <Search OnSearchChanged="SearchChanged" /> -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <DownLoadTable Downloads="downloadList" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <Pagination MetaData="MetaData" Spread="2" SelectedPage="SelectedPage" />
    </div>
</div>

@code {
public partial class FileDownload
    {
        [Parameter]
        public bool State { get; set; }

        public MetaData MetaData { get; set; } = new();

        private ProductParameters _productParameters = new ProductParameters();

        private IEnumerable<Download> downloadList { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        IDownloadService _downloadService { get; set; }

        private async Task SelectedPage(int page)
        {
            _productParameters.PageNumber = page;
            await GetProducts();
        }

        private async Task GetProducts()
        {
            var pagingResponse = await _downloadService.GetAll(_productParameters);
            downloadList = pagingResponse.Items;
            MetaData = pagingResponse.MetaData;
        }

        public async Task Save()
        {
            StateHasChanged();
            Console.WriteLine("NEVER CALLED");
        }

        protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
           await  GetProducts();
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea, what I possibly could do after an upload, so it refreshes the FileDownload component with its child component.

Best Alex

[image]

Comment: Your code is incomplete, presumably because it is not the real code, so a specific answer is difficult, but you see where you have `<FileDownload State="State" />` - toggle that State variable just before you call `StateHasChanged()` in `RefreshPageDownload`. Reason: Blazor will track `State` and if it hasn't changed, there is no need to render the component. Change the value and it will render.

Comment: Yes the code with  Edit State="State", I was trying stuff out,
When RefreshPageDownload-function is triggered (when an upload happened), 
 I tried it with StateHasChanged() but nothing happened.

Comment: You need something to change in the parameters of the FileDownload component - or Blazor will optimise out and not re-render. toggling that State boolean would do

Comment: Yes it works now, ty very much!

Comment: Added as an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

During the render cycle, Blazor will check known types (bool is one) for changes to their value.

If *all parameters* are known to have **not changed**, the component will **not** be submitted for re-rendering.

Adding a simple parameter, like a `bool` and toggling its value when you want to enable a render is one simple method to use.

In this case, if you toggle the "State" variable in `RefreshPageDownload`, then Blazor will include that component in processing the current render cycle.